# Dome light in bathroom, unable to get the glass dome off. Seems like a photosensor under the nipple

Tags: lighting, bathroom, ceiling

We have a dome ceiling light in our bathroom. We need to replace one of the bulbs but we are unable to get the dome off.

We've googled and been unsuccessful on all the videos and sites we've found.

The glass dome will spin from the base.
The nipple is not screwed on and is made of plastic and disconnects easily but underneath it looks like a photosensor with a timer setting.

Anyone have suggestions on how we get the dome off?

[close up of underneath the nipple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3Re.jpg)
[image: dome light switched on]
[image: dome light fixture off]
[image: dome light with nipple removed]

Comment: You may have to remove the fixture from the ceiling to replace a bulb. Have you tried rotating the base?

Comment: Does the metal trim ring at the bottom have threads?

Comment: @Huesmann there doesn't appear to be threads

Comment: @Barry we can rotate the base. We'll try to rotate it continually to see if it will release.